# Work in relation to introducing a positively charged object into a positively charged sphere

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, work

A text I am reading claims that when one introduces a small positively charged ball (B) into a positively charged metallic sphere (A) (through a tiny hole, with a thread), one performs work. This then leads to a higher voltage for B (the ball), when compared to A (the sphere; see picture).

My doubt is the following:
The inside of the sphere should be electrically neutral, so why would this be performing work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The inside of the sphere would have no electrical field, if it did not contain a charge, but, in this case it does, so there will be electrical field originating at the surface of the ball (B).

If a positive unit charge is moved from infinity to the ball (B) inside the sphere, the required work would be a little greater that the work required to bring the charge just to the surface of the sphere. Therefore, keeping in mind the definition of the potential, the potential on the ball would be a little higher than the potential on the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

"Introducing ball $B$ into sphere $A$" means moving ball $B$ all the way from infinity, via the tiny hole, into the sphere. Once ball $B$ reaches the hole, you are correct in assuming that pushing it inwards would not require additional work. But, you cannot ignore the work performed from infinity to the hole.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify matters I will write about positive charges moving rather than electrons moving the other way.

Let the system under consideration be the positively charged conducting ball and the positively charged conducting shell.

The diagram is missing some charges.
There will be negative induced charges on the inner surface of the shell and the positive charges would be resident on the outer surface of the shell.
The negative charge on the inner surface of the shell would equal the positive charges resident on the ball.
The positive charge on the outer surface of the shell would equal the positive charge on the shell before the ball was inside it plus the positive charge on the ball.
There will be an electric field inside the shell with a direction from the ball to the inner surface of the shell.
This means that the potential of the ball is higher than that of the shell.
The system has electric potential energy.
Connecting a conducting wire from the ball to the inner surface of the shell will result in positive charges moving from the ball and neutralising the negative charges on the inner surface of the shell.
In this process heat will be generated.

Where does the electric potential energy come from?

When the ball was outside the shell there would have been a repulsive force between the positive ball and the positive shell; indeed the ball on the string might never have entered inside the shell if the repulsive force was large enough.
To move the ball towards the shell work would have to be done by an external force.
This would increase the electrical potential energy of the system some of which would be converted into heat when the ball was inside the shell and connected to the shell with a wire.

—-

In fact this is the basis of the operation of a Van de Graaff generator where charges are moved upwards on a belt made of an insulator into a conducting shell and then transferred to the outside of the shell.
The external force/torque to move the charges on the belt is provided by an electric motor or a hand crank.